# Which one has the correct punctuation of these two sentences?

Tags: commas

- I, not he am doing the project.
- They, not he are the criminals.

   
  or
- I, not he, am doing the project.
- They, not he, are the criminals.

Comment: In the first and third examples, the first comma should be immediately after "I", not immediately before "not".

Answer (score 2):

ooo... comma rules can get a bit grey with your particular flavour of English but in this case I think everyone stands united. Well at least in theory.

Have a look at [rule 5 here](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp). The "not he" is an optional element (we could put parenthesis around it) so needs commas front and back